# A contradictory thought process of a simple problem

Tags: kinematics

Lets say there are 2 point particles A and B separated by a distance $x_{0}$ whose velocities are $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ along the positive X-axis respectively such that $v_{1}>v_{2}$

[image: img]

We can clearly see that at some time, A will over take B.

Now we consider the exact scenario in a different way.

A covers $x_{0}$ in $t_{0}s$. In the $t_{0}s$, B covers a distance $x_{1}$. A covers $x_{1}$ in $t_{1}s$ and so on. Now every time A reaches B's old position, B has already moved forward from there.

[image: img2]

After a while, $x_{n}$ is very small but still not 0. Then how exactly does A overtake B?

Comment: More on [Zeno's Paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%2Aeno+paradox).

Comment: You have successfully shown that when $A$ reaches $x_n$, he has not overtaken $B$.  This is indeed true for every $n$.  But you haven't addressed what happens after $A$ has passed all of the $x_n$'s.

Comment: To what @march said, this particular paradox is a very well known paradox from the ancient Greek era.  It was finally resolved in the general case via calculus.

Comment: Closely related (Zeno's paradoxes): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/98459/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/116955/226902 https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/102588/226902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time taken to overtake by the first method is obviously

$$\frac{x_o}{v_1-v_2}$$

By the second method, the time taken is given by the infinite series:
$$\frac{x_o}{v_1} \left(1 + \frac{v_2}{v_1}+ \frac{v_2^2}{v_1^2} ... \right ) =  
\frac{x_o}{v_1 (1-v_2/v_1)}= \frac{x_o}{v_1-v_2} $$

Where is the paradox? An infinite series can give a  finite answer.

Comment: So actually, it was just another way to think of the same thing. I got confused there and I thought that A could never overtake B.

Comment: Yes. The _paradox_ was that you were inadvertently summing the above series to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

If A is faster than B, we know that eventually, A will overtake B.
x<sub>n</sub> will indeed never be 0, but **it is because we are only considering things before A overtakes B.** Suppose A's speed is twice that of B and it took a time t<sub>0</sub> for A to come to initial position of B. For next x<sub>2</sub> distance, it will take t<sub>0</sub>/2, for x<sub>3</sub> time interval will be t<sub>0</sub>/4 and so on. After a while, x<sub>n</sub> will be low, but the time interval taken by A to cover x<sub>n</sub> will also be very low.
The sum of time interval will be:
t<sub>0</sub>(1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 ....) and so on till infinite terms.
This sum is actually finite(Its sum of **infinite GP**, you can look it up) and total time taken will be 2t<sub>0</sub>. **The problem in your approach was that you were considering only distance and not time**. Therefore you never reached the instant 2t<sub>0</sub>, where A overtakes B.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).